# Schengen ATV required for Toronto > New Delhi, via Lisbon and Vienna?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit-visas, schengen-visas

I have a transit visa question.

I am an Indian citizen, and I will be traveling from Toronto, to New Delhi, via Lisbon Portugal and Vienna Austria, through the TAP Airline

Similarly, I'll be coming back to Canada, with valid travel documents, via some Schengen countries, in under 10 days.

I can't find out clearly, whether I need transit visa for this itenarary.

As per Emirates transit visa tool, [looks like I don't need one](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&AC=CA&AV=Canada&DC=IN&DV=India&TC=PT%2CAT&TV=Portugal%2CAustria&h=a0723cca3633d8941cc93fdab8fc0eccd38ef5)

But since as an Indian citizen, I need a visa for pretty much everywhere, I am confused.
I also read in other answers here that if you're just touching one Schengen area, you don't need an ATV, but I am touching two, which confuses me further.

Any help please?
Sorry if this is duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area); top answer, first title applies to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "Schengen Airport Transit Visa". What you will need for this itinerary is a regular multi entry Schengen Visa.

The reason that you need this is that you are taking an internal Schengen flight. For the purpose of immigration control the whole of Schengen can be considered as if it was one country, and an internal Schengen flight is like a domestic flight in the US or Canada. There is no passport control when flying within the Schengen area.

So you will need to pass passport control and enter the Schengen area to be able to take your flight to Vienna. Then in Vienna you will pass passport control again, now leaving the Schengen area.

It does not matter that you will only spend a few hours within Europe. You will need this Schengen visa, and this for both ways. Hence get a multi entry one.

If you are flying a route that would only touch one airport within the Schengen area, so without an internal flight, then you do not need a Schengen visa. You will be able to stay in the airside non-Schengen transit zone.

But you might still need an Airport Transit Visa (issued by the country involved) under certain circumstances. The rules differ by country, but usually Indian nationals with valid Canadian or US residence permits would not need a transit visa when transitting through Europe on their way between North America and India. But do check.

Comment: The first sentence is incorrect, Airport Transit Visas exist for the Schengen area.

Comment: Maybe this is just a matter of semantics. I have never seen mention of an "Schengen Airport Transit Visa" as such, only that some Schengen countries require an ATV from some nationalities.

Comment: Regulation (EC) No 810/2009 states that certain nationalities must have an airport transit visa (called exactly like that), also called visa type A, to transit through airports. In some cases individual Member States are allowed to add additional nationalities.

Comment: "For the purpose of immigration control the whole of Schengen can be considered as if it was one country" - This was very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @KristvanBesien Looks like the ATVs do exist for Schengen : https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/transit-schengen-visa/

Comment: Schengenvisainfo is not an official site. 
My argument is that Airport Transit Visas are still handled by the individual countries, and are thus country specific visa, not Schengen Visa. If you for example get an ATV to transit Amsterdam it will be issued by the Netherlands per their own rules, not the Schengen code.